# ObservableCollection updating from one method but not another

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a method that updates my observableCollection

```
public void UpdateBeat()
{
    SequenceCollection = new ObservableCollection<Sequence>();

    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);

    SequenceCollection.Add(new Sequence(1, 2));            
}
```

I have 2 different methods fired from events - the view updates from 1 of the methods but not the other.

```
//Does not work
private void BsOnUpdateStep(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("BS Update");
    UpdateBeat();
}

//Works
void total_AudioAvailable(object sender, AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ASIO Written");
    UpdateBeat();
}
```

I have no idea what the difference could be here. The only thing I can tell is that the 1st method fires more often than the 2nd. I cannot get the 2nd to work at all.

Comment: Just a random guess: Some kind of multithreading issue? When and how are your events fired?

Comment: I guess we need more information/code

Comment: Events are fired when audio is received from the audio driver, and updated at specific time intervals.  I know the events are running on different threads.  Is there a way to handle this with UI updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your calls to UpdateBeat are from different threads but ObservableCollection is not thread safe, that is why -probably- you have such strange results.

You should look for an concurrent ObservableCollection.

One such implementation can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/414407/Thread-Safe-Improvement-for-ObservableCollection

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private SequenceCollection = new ObservableCollection<Sequence>();
Random random = new Random();

public void UpdateBeat()
{
    int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);

    SequenceCollection.Add(new Sequence(1, 2));            
}
```

I put the `Random` instantiation outside of the method too as you should only instantiate this once to get a proper stream of random numbers.